# Using abstract factory with Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, configuration, dependency-injection

I have some Abstract Factory

```
public interface AbstractViewersFactory {
    IAbstractShapeViewer createRectangle(BaseOperationsListener<RectangleDTO> p);
    IAbstractShapeViewer createOval(BaseOperationsListener<OvalDTO> p);
    IAbstractShapeViewer createTriangle(BaseOperationsListener<TriangleDTO> p);
}
```

And Its implementation *Draw2DViewersFactory*.
Now, I want create some class that will take responsibility for creating presenters/viewers by model and configurate it by Spring.
So, I need describe in *.xml* configuration what method it should call. 
It can be something like this (pseudo config)

```
<bean creator>
<constructor-args>
<list>
    <bean describe-item> <constructor-args>model=Rectangle.class, method-for-viewer-create="createRectangle"</args>
    <bean describe-item> <constructor-args>model=Oval.class, method-for-viewer-create="createOval"</args>
<list>
</constructor-args>
</bean>
```

How I can do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please explain further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though your question is very unclear, I think I got what you wanted to know.
You can define a spring bean as a factory instance and then set the factory method of this bean like this:

```
<bean id="myFactoryBean"
  class="AbstractViewersFactory">

  <bean id="exampleBean"
  factory-bean="myFactoryBean"
  factory-method="createRectangle"/>
```

Hope this helps.
Google this for further information :p

greetings

Comment: actually since AbstractViewersFactory is an interface, the answer should use `<bean id="myFactoryBean" class="Draw2DViewersFactory">`